# React-native: any advantage including @2x picture?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, native, pixel

The official React Native documentation says you can include a `@2x` and `@3x` images for every picture in the project: [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images).

However, including that extra `@2x` increases bundle size by a lot. And the only advantage is it takes less CPU to draw that `@2x` on screen.

So is it worth it include a `@2x`? Or I can just use a single `@3x` format? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When building a native mobile app (using any system), one reason to include multiple versions of assets is better optimization of images. Instead of trusting everyone's different devices to properly resize an image down, you can be sure that it will render correctly by packaging an image at exactly the size you need. Also, you have finer grained control of how aliasing works, especially when creating multiple raster images from a vector as opposed to scaling a raster down itself. You can get better looking images for @1x and @2x devices if you do it yourself vs forcing the device to resize a large image.  In some cases, you may actually decide to slightly change your icon depending on the device's screen capabilities. Maybe the icon is slightly thicker on @1x than it is on @3x because the @3x has the pixel density to support thinner lines.

Also, you should check out [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/mac) for reducing the file size of assets. I use it a lot at work and often get a 60% file size reduction with no visible changes to the image.